# Inconsistent id refs in mongo/typegoose project

Tags: mongodb, typegoose

When debugging my mongodb/typegoose backed I found out that I have a very inconsistent way of referring to related fields.

```
tags: [
  ObjectId("61e73da868987d7565732dce"),
  ObjectId("61e73f9468987d7565732dd7"),
  ObjectId("61e73f9c68987d7565732ddb"),
  '61ec8ef155cdf0cbb4260c58'
],
author: '61d635ef6a034c77e36d5dc0',
```

which is definitely a result of my experiments and lack of expertise with databases.

Apparently, it doesn't matter for finding documents, all four tags get properly connected and retrieved.

Questions to those in the know - can such inconsistency lead to problems, should one prefer ObjectIds or plain strings?

Answer (score 0):

As long as the fields in the mongoose schema (typegoose class) are defined as having a value type of `ObjectId`, mongoose should auto-cast strings to ObjectId.

Comment: I thought this is what `ref` was responsible for in decorators, as in `@prop({ ref: () => Ticket, type: () => String })`

Comment: i dont quite know what you mean, but with `type: () => String` you are effectively setting the field type (as stored in the database) to `String`, not `ObjectId`, you can define references without the `type` option if its for `ObjectId`, or manually setting `type: () => mongoose.Types.ObjectId`